# fire ajax call only if the form validates

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, validation

I am using bootstrap form validator script for my form which is being submitted through ajax.
The problem is even if validation fails the script gets submitted

this is validation code

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  event.stopPropagation();
              }
              form.classList.add('was-validated');
          }, false);
      });
  }, false);
})();
```

If I place a function below this to execute ajax call that submits the form it submits even if form isn't validated.

this is the form code

```
<div class="form-group text-white needs-validation" novalidate>

        <form method="POST" id="rform" action="javascript:return">
```

Comment: Do you have any constrains on your form elements like "required", "min", "max" etc ? Also not `novalidate` is at wrong place (should be as an `<form>` attribute)

Comment: yes i have some feilds with min attribute

Answer (score 0):

You missed the adding the class `needs-validation` that your Javascript code needs and `novalidate`

```html
<form method="POST" id="rform" action="" novalidate class="needs-validation">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" required> <br> 
   ID: <input type="text" name="registration_id" min="3"> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I would just try that.